# which file(s) to modify in geotools source code to have different anchor points for directions(N,W,E,S,NW, ...) for point labels for maxDisplacement?

Tags: java, label, geoserver, geotools, sld

which file(s) to modify in geotools or geoserver source code to have different anchor points for directions(N,W,E,S,NW, ...) for point labels if maxDisplacement is used? If I use anchor point (1, 0.5) in geoserver sld file with maxDisplacement vendor option, all remaining directions(N,W,E,S,...) placing point text labels with anchor point define in sld, I want change anchor point for remaining directions or angles, how to achieve this, I found this file in geotools source code "...\geotools-24.1-project\geotools-24.1\modules\library\render\src\main\java\org\geotools\renderer\label\LabelCacheImpl.java", I changed RIGHT_UP_ANCHOR_CANDIDATES, RIGHT_DOWN_ANCHOR_CANDIDATES, ... in this file with no success, any suggestions?

[Point_Label_AnchorPoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7kTJ.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: needs more clarity - examples of code (since java was listed as a label) should be entered into message

Comment: geotools-24.1\modules\library\render\src\main\java\org\geotools\renderer\label\LabelCacheImpl.java related to geotools and geoserver & this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/390822/how-to-achieve-different-anchor-point-based-on-n-w-e-s-nw-ne-sw-se-for-po

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to achieve? It is not normal to need to make changes to the library

Comment: Please refer snapshot, https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7kTJ.png

Comment: any suggestions or update?

Comment: once you allow displacement, you pretty much give up control over the placement of the label.

Comment: @IanTurton how to control point label if maxDisplacement vendor option is used? I have to change source code, if yes which file(s) to change? reply will be greatly appreciated